# Does Carbon Design System have utility classes for spacing?

Tags: css, sass

I'm new to Carbon Design System and have previous experience with Bootstrap.

In Bootstrap there are [utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#notation) for spacing. For example `.mb-2` applies `margin-bottom` condition with the `-2` being equivalent to `$spacer * .5`. This means it can easily be used in HTML.

The [docs](https://carbondesignsystem.com/elements/spacing/overview#applying-spacing) for Carbon say

> The spacing scale can be applied to `margin` or `padding` properties, as well as to both vertical and horizontal edges. The token takes the place of the values normally assigned to margin and padding.

It then gives examples

> The following are all approved ways to syntactically apply Carbon spacing tokens:

```
margin: $spacing-03;
// ... other examples
```

I understand that I can use these in my own Sass file to generate similar utility classes to Bootstrap e.g.

```
@use '@carbon/layout';

// 24px margin-top
.mt-24 {
    margin-top: layout.$spacing-06;
}
```

But I'm surprised this is the only way to do it because it relies on me either:

1. Generating any/all utility classes my application might need. As per `.mt-24` above.
2. Using these declarations in my Sass file on certain elements e.g.

   ```
    .some-element {
        // ...
        margin-top: layout.$spacing-06;
    }

    .some-other-element {
        // ...
        margin-top: layout.$spacing-06;
    }
   ```

The second option seems a poor approach because it avoids DRY to achieve the same as adding `.mt-24` as a HTML class to whatever elements need it.

Am I missing something here, or should I be generating the utility classes as per option 1?

Comment: There’s indeed nothing in the docs, but I found [this code](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon/blob/ef9501b2ba375f9e6134f700d9e5b66d60cdc910/www/src/components/Box/Box.module.scss) in the repository, for generating utility classes. Not sure if its exposed by the library somehow or if you have to copy it over to use it.